# How to Show or Hide DIV tag depending on query result in PHP?

Tags: php, html, logic, conditional-statements

I want to implement a web program where by each time a web page loads a php function checks the database to see whether the user belongs to a particular committee or not. If Yes; then particular **`<DIV>`** tags will be visible, If No then the **`<DIV>`** tags will be hidden.

Below is the sample php code i used to implement the logic but failed.

```
 $style = "\"visibility:visible\"";

 function checkCommitteeID($UserID)
{
 $sql = "SELECT CommitteeID FROM CommitteeMembers
 WHERE CommitteeMembersStatusID = 1 AND UserID = '$UserID' ";
 $result = sqlsrv_query($db, $sql);
 $CommitteeID = 0;

    if ($myrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
      {
        $CommitteeID  = $myrow['CommitteeID'];
      }
  return $CommitteeID;
}

  $CommitteeID = checkCommitteeID($UserID);

 if ($CommitteeID > 0)
   {
     $style = "\"visibility:visible\"";
   }
 else
   {
     $style = "\"visibility:hidden\"";
   }
```

The style variable represents the value of the **`<DIV>`** tag's attribute. The **`<DIV>`** tag is as shown below

```
<div align="center" style=<?php echo $style; ?> >
```

When i run the web page the DIV tags are hidden regardless of whether the user exists in a committee or not. Whats wrong with my code?? Or can someone show me how to implement it in a better way?

Comment: Y do you want to keep the DIV in DOM? Display the DIV only if it's required. Don't toggle the visibility

Comment: You are entering the else condition.

Comment: try `return $style;` and `$style = checkCommitteeID(ID);`, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't declare $db variable in your function, if you declared it outside the function you should add

```
global $db;
```

at the beginning of your function before declaring $sql.

Comment: You've kinda helped me realize where the problem was. I've solved the issue by putting the $db variable as a parameter.

function checkCommitteeID($db, $UserID)

Then calling it with:

$CommitteeID = checkCommitteeID($db, $UserID);

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem related to style then you can use

```
if ($CommitteeID > 0)
   {
     $style = "\"display:block\"";
   }
 else
   {
     $style = "\"display:none\"";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick too.

```html
<div <?php echo (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)?'visible':'hidden'; ?> ></div>
```

And similarly, you can do it for a table tag as well in case you need to SHOW/HIDE entire table depending on query result in PHP.

```html
<table <?php echo (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)?'visible':'hidden'; ?> ></table>
```